# Can i find a django web development Mentor here at Stackoverflow?

Tags: django

I am a beginner programmer not just in django development. Its getting more and more complicated and can't keep working solo.

Was wondering if its possible to find a django mentor here(stackoverflow), so many great developers here.
thank you.

Comment: most likely not, since that is not was SO is for

Comment: @catherine if i could, i would..

Comment: hire me for django development

Comment: @masterofdestiny am sure i cant afford your expertise..but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question will most likely get closed, but my suggestion would be this:

Learn these technologies in this order:

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript
- SQL
- A server-side language. Python is probably the easiest to get started with. Check out [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/)

Call me old-fashioned, but I find that paper books are still easier to learn from than digital. For me, they are simply more tactile, and faster. If you just want to dive in head first, and you want to use Django, start with [The Definitive Guide to Django](http://djangobook.com/), follwed by [Practical Django Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219386), then [Django Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847197566) finishing up with [Pro Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210478).